# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Authorization required

Tags: python, automated-tests, appium, browserstack, python-appium

Was trying to run the python API automation  through DriverScript.py but getting the error as :
PS C:\Users\Shibin.R\Downloads\retail-east-connectedcustomer-main\retail-east-connectedcustomer-main> python DriverScript.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Shibin.R\Downloads\retail-east-connectedcustomer-main\retail-east-connectedcustomer-main\DriverScript.py", line 62, in 
mobile=Mobile(platform,report,script,device,argDict["testData"]["location"])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Shibin.R\Downloads\retail-east-connectedcustomer-main\retail-east-connectedcustomer-main\FunctionLibrary\Generic\Mobile\GenericFunctions.py", line 146, in **init**
self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Shibin.R\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py", line 257, in **init**
super().**init**(
File "C:\Users\Shibin.R\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 206, in **init**
self.start_session(capabilities)
File "C:\Users\Shibin.R\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py", line 346, in start_session
response = self.execute(RemoteCommand.NEW_SESSION, w3c_caps)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Shibin.R\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 345, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\Shibin.R\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_response
raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Authorization required

Tried installing all the Required packages.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are getting this error:

```
exception_class(value) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Authorization required
```

Could you please make sure if you are using correct BrowserStack credentials?

You can find your credentials on Browserstack dashboard.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).